# Getting anon when trying to get loogged in user [Symfony 3.4] FOSUserBundke+Lexik+FosRest

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4, fosrestbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm new in symfony and tried to implement a auth service that allows me to register+login+getting the logged in user for my angular app.
the login worked like a charm, got the token and connected successfully to the app, but when I tried to get the logged in user via token, I get "anon" when I tested it in postman, It's kinda weird because I checked every related post in github/stackoverflow, but none of them worked, I'm stuck for 6 hours now. Here is some of my code.

the method in my controller :

```
/**
     * @Route("/get/profile", name="api_get_user")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function getUserAction()
    {
 
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
 
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
 
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('response' => 'OK', 'data'=> $jsonContent)));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return  $response;
    }
```

My Security.yml :

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
 
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
 
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
 
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
 
        healthcheck:
            pattern: ^/ping$
            anonymous: true
 
        api_docs:
            pattern: ^/doc
            anonymous: true
 
        api_register:
            pattern: ^/register
            anonymous: true
 
        api_password_reset:
            pattern: ^/password/reset
            anonymous: true
 
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                require_previous_session: false
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
 
 
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator : security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
 
 
            logout: true
            anonymous: true
 
    access_control:
 
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

my User class :

```
<?php
 
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMSSerializer;
 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
  */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMSSerializer\Expose
     * @JMSSerializer\Type("string")
     * @JMSSerializer\Groups({"users_all","users_summary"})
     */
    protected $id;
 
    /**
     * @JMSSerializer\Expose
     * @JMSSerializer\Type("string")
     * @JMSSerializer\Groups({"users_all","users_summary"})
     */
    protected $username;
 
    /**
     * @var string The email of the user.
     *
     * @JMSSerializer\Expose
     * @JMSSerializer\Type("string")
     * @JMSSerializer\Groups({"users_all","users_summary"})
     */
    protected $email;
 
 
}
```

As I said in postman when I put the token I get
anon as a response it means anonymous and I don't know why.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle?

Comment: Yes I'm using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Comment: Ok so you have to use the custom authenticator provided https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration > lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the fosUserBundle, I guess it was from fosUserBundle, I don 't know what happened but it works